# Xamarin.Forms Exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, binding

I'm very new at Xamarin.Forms and I have one issue that I can't solve.

When I click on a button, it is supposed to navigate to page RegistracijaKorisnika.xaml (It is on Bosnian language .. sorry for that), but it does not because of the exception:

**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**

The page RegistracijaKorisnika.xaml has ViewModel page RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel.cs and when i put in RegistracijaKorisnika.xaml.cs line :

```
BindingContext = new RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel()
```

The exception occurs.

When I delete line

```
BindingContext = new RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel()
```

I can navigate to the RegistracijaKorisnika.xaml.
Here is the code and I am hoping that you can help me.

This is RegistracijaKorisnika.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ITJobFinder.View.RegistracijaKorisnika">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Placeholder="Ime" x:Name="entryImeKorisnika" Text="{Binding ImeKorisnika}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Prezime" x:Name="entryPrezimeKorisnika" Text="{Binding PrezimeKorisnika}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Email" x:Name="entryEmailKorisnika" Text="{Binding EmailKorisnika}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Password" x:Name="entryPasswordKorisnika" Text="{Binding PasswordKorisnika}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Naziv zavrsene obrazovne institucije" x:Name="entryNazivFakulteta" Text="{Binding NazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika}"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Godina zavrsetka obrazovanja" x:Name="entryGodinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja" Text="{Binding GodinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja}"/>
            <Button Text="Registruj se!" Command="{Binding SaveNewUser}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is RegistracijaKorisnika.xaml.cs

```
namespace ITJobFinder.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RegistracijaKorisnika : ContentPage
    {
        public RegistracijaKorisnika ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = new RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

This is RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel.cs

```
namespace ITJobFinder.ViewModel
{
    public class RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string imeKorisnika;
        private string prezimeKorisnika;
        private string emailKorisnika;
        private string passwordKorisnika;
        private string nazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika;
        private string godinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja;

        public string ImeKorisnika
        {
            get => imeKorisnika;
            set
            {
                imeKorisnika = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string PrezimeKorisnika
        {
            get => PrezimeKorisnika;
            set
            {
                prezimeKorisnika = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string EmailKorisnika
        {
            get => emailKorisnika;
            set
            {
                emailKorisnika = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string PasswordKorisnika
        {
            get => passwordKorisnika;
            set
            {
                passwordKorisnika = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string NazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika
        {
            get => nazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika;
            set
            {
                nazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string GodinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja
        {
            get => godinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja;
            set
            {
                godinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand SaveNewUser { get; private set; }
        private DataBaseContext _context;

        public RegistracijaKorisnikaViewModel()
        {
            _context = new DataBaseContext();
            SaveNewUser = new Command(SaveUser);

        }
        void SaveUser()
        {
            Korisnik k = new Korisnik
            {
                ImeKorisnika = ImeKorisnika,
                PrezimeKorisnika = PrezimeKorisnika,
                EmailKorisnika = EmailKorisnika,
                PasswordKorisnika = PasswordKorisnika,
                GodinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja = GodinaZavrsetkaObrazovanja,
                NazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika = NazivObrazovanjaKOrisnika
            };
            _context.Korisnici.Add(k);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u comment out this line and try again: `SaveNewUser = new Command(SaveUser);` ? And if you are using visual studio, can u press F5/Continue after the Exception is thrown? It will most likely show a more elaborate exception in the console output

Comment: @Csharpest I commented that line but ther was the same exception. When i press Continue this is showing in my output

Comment: 08-14 18:37:02.755 E/mono    (12983): Unhandled Exception:
08-14 18:37:02.755 E/mono    (12983): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Ok this doesnt get us anywhere. Jason got a good point, look at his answer. Other than that, it might be your DBContext or your BaseViewModel class. Or are u hiding something from the RegistracijaKorisnika class?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, Jason was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this get will cause an self-referential loop - your get should be using the lower-case internal variable, not the upper case Property name

```
   public string PrezimeKorisnika
    {
        // should be "prezimeKorisnika"
        get => PrezimeKorisnika;
        set
        {
            prezimeKorisnika = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. these stupid mistakes happens all the time. Thank youuuu